# Rotating Image and points

Tags: geometry

I have a machine learning project for face recognition.

The faces can be close or far from camera, and also they can be inclined to any side. We are given the $E_l$ (left eye) and $E_r$ (right eye) positions of each face.
The first step I'm doing is to resize images based on $||E_r-E_l||$ so the distance between the eyes same size for all images. I fixed it to 100 pixels.

So:

$scale=\frac{100}{||E_r-E_l||}$

$E_r'=E_r*scale$

$E_l'=E_l*scale$

Then I resized the image and drew squares in the new eyes positions of scaled images. Here is the result:

[image: Scaled image and scaled eyes positions]

So the $E_r'$ and $E_l'$ were calculated correctly.

Now, as you can see, the eyes aren't horizontally aligned. They must be.

Then I calculated the rotation angle:

$$\theta=-arctan(\frac{y(E_r')-y(E_l')}{x(E_r')-x(E_l')})$$

Then I rotate my image by $\theta$ having the following result:

[image: Rotated image]

Clearly we can see that the rotation worked.
But now the image size has changed, and I'm not sure how to rotate the eyes positions.

Unfortunately the y axis grows to bottom and x axis grows to right and the center is at top-left of image like this:

[image]

How can I calculate the new eyes positions?